# TYPO3 force internal links to cross domain pages to use https in news

Tags: https, typo3, typoscript, tx-news, typolink

my TYPO3 website has multiple domains that have links from internal news to another a page in another domain.

```
Domain A (with SSL in frontend)
  Page 1
  News (folder)
  News A
  News B
Domain B (with SSL in frontend)
  Page 2
  Page 3
```

Links in `News A` to Page 1 work perfectly fine, but when linking from News B to `Page 2` or `Page 3`, the url is generated properly, but the scheme is always `http`:

Example `News A`:
`<a href="/Page-1.html">Page 1</a>`

Example `News B`: `<a href="http://domain-b/Page-2.html">Page 2</a>`

Is there a way to configure the url generation to always use https as scheme when linking to anything in a given domain? I suspect that this has to be done for the link rendering in tx_news?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the news extension but is a bug in TYPO3 itself - or let's call it a missing feature because TYPO3 doesn't know at this place that the other domain should be use `https` as protocol.

What I do to solve this is a replace on the content before it is outputted. This can be done with adding a hook in the `ext_localconf.php`:

```
// Hook for changing output before showing it
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['tslib/class.tslib_fe.php']['contentPostProc-output'][]
  = \Vendor\ExtKey\Hooks\Frontend\ContentPostProc::class . '->run';
```

and in the file `typo3conf/extkey/Classes/Hooks/Frontend/ContentPostProc`:

namespace Vendor\ExtKey\Hooks\Frontend;

```
class ContentPostProc
{

  public function run(array &$parameters) {
        $searchReplace = [
            'http://domain.tld' => 'https://domain.tld'
        ];
        $parameters['pObj']->content = str_replace(array_keys($searchReplace), array_values($searchReplace), $parameters['pObj']->content);
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds pretty reasonnable, I'll check on the overall performance (but everything is cached statically in the end so this should not be a problem). What bothers me, is that it's possible to set the scheme on typolink, therefore I thought it was possible to configure this globally but as you say, this might just be a missing feature :-)